# Passing bytes from ASP.NET to Objective-C NSData

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, objective-c, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get byte data from a PDF file in ASP.NET C# MVC and send it to my objective-c project to display the PDF (can’t simply get the file in Objective-C due to permissions and windows)

Here is my example code:

```
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://nssdcftp.gsfc.nasa.gov/photo_gallery/image/spacecraft/pioneer10-11.jpg"];

NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

urlData returns 38051 bytes, so that was I am trying to get from my ASP.NET project.

In my ASP.NET project I got the Bytes of the PDF file like so:

```
item.data = File.ReadAllBytes(myPDFPath);
```

and it returns something like this:

```
JVBERi0xLjQgU2hhcnAgU2Nhbm5lZCBJbWFnZVBERgolU2hhcnAgTm9uLUVuY3J5cHRpb24KMyAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvUGFnZQovUGFyZW50IDEgMCBSCi9SZXNvdXJjZXMgNCAwIFIKL0Nvbn
```

so now I am trying to pass this to my objective-c project and I have tried the following:

```
-(NSArray *)GetPDFFileData:(NSString *)y
{
    NSString *FileBrowserRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?y=%@",kIP,y];
    NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:FileBrowserRequestString];
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    if(data == nil)
        return nil;
    NSError *myError;
    NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];
    return tableArray;
```

}

all I get returned is the long byte string, can I convert this into NSData ?

Or is there another way to go about this?

Full ASP.NET Code:

```
public List<PDFFileClass> getPDFFileData()
        {
            PDFCell = new List<PDFFileClass>();

            var myPDFPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myPDFPath"];

            PDFFileClass item = new PDFFileClass();

            item.data = File.ReadAllBytes(myPDFPath);

            PDFCell.Add(item);

            return PDFCell;

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns"? What returns? How did you serve that data? It looks like you're base64-encoding the binary data as *part* of the response, rather than just serving it as the whole response. But we can't tell, as you've only given us a single line of your ASP.NET code.

Comment: I added my full ASP.NET Code

Comment: Well that doesn't look like it's a suitable response to serve a single PDF file... what do you expect the response to contain?

Comment: `JVBERi0xLjQgU2hhcnAgU2Nhbm5lZCBJbWFnZVBERgolU2hhcnAgTm9uLUVuY3J5cHRpb24KMyAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvUGFnZQovUGFyZW50IDEgMCBSCi9SZXNvdXJjZXMgNCAwIFIKL0Nvbn` is an just the beginning of the string returned, the rest of the response was way to long to post

Comment: That looks like it's base64 encoded... Why would you not want to just serve the raw bytes?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't understand what you mean by 'Why would you not want to just serve the raw bytes?' How do I serve the raw bytes?

Comment: Well you don't return a list of anything, for a start...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90241/discussion-between-user979331-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: @JonSkeet how would you recommend I go about accomplishing what I want to accomplish ?

Comment: I think you need to start by having two different methods - one for fetching a single PDF raw, the other for getting information about multiple files. It doesn't help that we don't know what kind of asp.net project this is...